# Show non-json response from json API call

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, es6-promise, fetch-api

Shopping cart in browser calls API in Apache server to add product to cart using additem:

```
function addItem(product, quantity) {
    fetch('api/addItemToCart', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            product: [product],
            quantity: [quantity]
        })
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
            response.json().then(
                json => {
                    showErrorMessage(json.title);
                });
            return null;
        })
        .then((data) => {
            if (data == null)
                return;
            showMessage(data.title);
        })
        .catch(error => alert('addItem error', error));
}
```

If server or proxy is down, Apache returns html content as error message instead of requested json.

In this case  response.json() fails.

How to check for non-json response and show responce body in this case?

Code should probably use conditionally response.text() instead of response.json() .

ShowMessage() and showErrorMessage() injet text to span in page into bootstrap alert compoment.

Also

> if (data == null)
> return;

looks ugly.

This is ASP.NET 5 Core MVC application using Apache+Kestrel.

Comment: Why don't you check the response code at first? If the server is down, it should return a 500 or equivalent status code.

Comment: This is already checked first: ` if (response.ok)` return true if response code is in range 200..299 . Response codes 400 .. 599 may return or may not return json content: API call returns 400 code with json content on regular error or 4xx or 5xx code with non-json content on non-controlled exception